# Easy way to copy breakpoint in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

Is there an easy way to copy/move breakpoint to another line in Visual Studio?

There are scenarios when breakpoints may contain some conditions, tracing, etc. and it is not easy to copy/move it around during debugging session.

The only solution I see now is by import/export which is not really acceptable.

Comment: If import/export is not an acceptable solution, you're looking for a tool recommendation which is off-topic for this site. Try http://www.oz-code.com/

Answer (score 5):

What version of the Studio?

To move:

For 2013 and earlier, right-clik on the breakpoint and select "Location".

For 2015, hover over breakpoint's icon and click "Settings...".
In the location area, you can change the name of the file and the line number.

There is no obvious way to copy. How bad do you need it? Someone may write an extension to do that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can export break point in xml file and when required import that xml file to visual studio again. There is option from export/import in break point window of visual studio.

Check this article for detail : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/setting-breakpoints-in-visual-studio/

Comment: @TaW - just import and export breakpoint ...that is the easy way ..what is more easy way than that...

Comment: This is neither really easy to use for a single breakpoint nor do I see how it can be used to move or copy breakpoints to a different line of code.

Comment: Yes, import/export is a bit of a mess and not really acceptable. I also couldn't find any plugins which can help with that.

Comment: I disagree, this is very helpful. For example, I set a bunch of breakpoints in project "**a**" in solution **A1**. Project "**a**" is also referenced in solution **B1** . But if I need to debug the same lines of code in solution **B1** I would have to look all through solution **A1** and manually copy every breakpoint from project "**a**"  in **A1** to project "**a**" in solution **B1**. For this, this answer works without a hitch.